# Phone is being overrun with ads

Tags: ads

Whenever I switch on my Internet every morning I get a page which opens up with applications and games that aren't from the Play Store and I see a message that says my phone has stopped outside applications from being downloaded. Plus my gallery gets flooded with pictures of game icons and stuff and no matter how many times I delete them, they come back again. How do I make this stop?

Comment: You have installed something a bit dodgy by the sounds of it. Try AVG or AVAST security (both are free on play store) and see if they find the app then uninstall it. You could factory reset if it gets very bad, but lets not do that first!

Comment: I would never recommend an anti-virus Android app. They are bloating and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have downloaded an app using an advertising platform that uses these ads.

These ads are actually *against* Google Play's Developer Policies, so when you find the app (see below) that is doing this, be sure to report it.

There are a few ways to find the app:

- When did the adverts start? If you can remember this, try and think of any apps you might have installed not long before they started, and uninstall them.
- Are there any apps in your Manage Apps area that shouldn't be there? Uninstall them, and see if the adverts go away.
- Check through all your apps, and look at the permissions. Adverts like these will need loads of permissions, so if you see an app with many permissions which it may not need, uninstall it and see if the adverts go.

If the worst comes to the worst, you can factory reset and reinstall all your apps one by one, however this is a last resort, as you *will* lose all of your data.